# Setting up the GRUB for future use

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, partitioning

What I am currently working on is trying to set up my partitions/ grub to eventually dual-boot. Currently for partitions, I have:

- the Ubuntu partition, mounted to '/', also flagged 'boot'
- a second, empty partition where the other linux system will go
- the 'extended', and 'swap' partitions

How do I set up the grub to eventually handle the boot?

Result of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   133627903    66812928   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       150013950   156301311     3143681    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       133627904   150011903     8192000   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       150013952   156301311     3143680   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Could add results of `sudo fdisk -l` to the question. Well I suppose that grub auto probe other partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Boot flag only applies to Windows, grub does not use boot flag. But a few motherboard have a BIOS that needs to see a boot flag, so we still suggest you have one on a primary partition.

It depends on the other system you install. Most systems will install their boot loader to the MBR overwriting you current grub boot loader in MBR.

If that system is another Linux with grub2 you can just boot into Ubuntu and run this to reinstall Ubuntu's grub into MBR of sda, if that is your drive.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

You can also use Supergrub to boot your install or use Boot-Repair to install grub to your MBR.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

If other install is grub2, it may remember where it installed and on major updates reinstall its grub to MBR. You an repair again, but may be able to un-configure the reinstall locations, or originally install grub to that install's PBR or partition boot sector. The PBR will not boot on its own and is just a location, so you do not have issues.

to get grub2 to remember where to reinstall on updates:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Enter thru first pages,spacebar to choose/unchoose drive, enter to accept, do not choose partitions normally. If you do not want it to reinstall un-choose everything.